# Как сохранить все фото, отправленные пользователем? aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как сохранить все фото, отправленные пользователем? Код ниже сохраняет только одно фото, т.к, каждое фото в новом сообщении, как я понял.

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def get_photo(message: types.Message):
    await message.photo[-1].download()
```

Answer (score 1):

`await message.photo[-1].download('data/send-' + message.photo[-1].file_unique_id + '.jpg')`

я тоже бился над этим и в итоге сделал как-то так.
Может и костыль, но работает