# Как реализовать сохранение фото и видео которые присылают пользователи боту?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Я пишу бота на Python библиотека Aiogram , задумка следующая , боту присылают фотографии или видео, или присылают фотографии и видео вместе и нужно чтобы он сохранял фото в своем корне в формате `/photos/+ сегодняшняя дата/+photo.jpg или video.mp4`, то есть должна создаваться папка с сегодняшней датой и туда должны идти фото и видео. Я знаю что можно использовать `content type ['photo', 'video']`,но не совсем понятно как можно реализовать сохранение, надеюсь на ваше объяснение. Я видел похожий вопрос как сохранять фото, но в моем вопросе есть отличие, мне нужно сохранить в конкретную папку и сделать чтобы создавалась папка каждый день новая с названием в виде даты. Выше я указал формат в котором должно быть сохранение, то есть должно быть сохранение еще и видео, не только фото, все должно быть одним методом желательно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сохранить все фото, отправленные пользователем? aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274960/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-aiogram)

Comment: я видел данный ответ, но он не объясняет в моем случае, там просто указано как сохранить фото

Comment: в моем же случае вопрос звучит иначе

Comment: Нет, вы просто должны запихнуть файл в папку с названием текущей даты. Я считаю что это то же самое. Или вы не знаете как получить текущую дату?

Comment: да я не знаю, и не знаю сделать путь именно с датой, было бы не плохо если объясните и поможете составить handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def get_photo(message: types.Message):
    date = f"{datetime.now().day}.{datetime.now().month}.{datetime.now().year}"
    path = os.path.join('photos', date, message.photo[-1].file_unique_id + '.png')
    await message.photo[-1].download(destination_file=path)
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но можно больше объяснений по порядку? От времени и до сохранения.

Comment: И с видео будет похожий вариант?

Comment: @Alex да с видео почти то же самое. Только поменяйте `photo` на `video` и еще расширение файла